# Delete rows based on age, status and existence of related rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
create table the_table (
  id integer, root_id integer, parent_id integer, status text, ts timestamp, comment text);
insert into the_table values
(1, null, null, 'COMPLETE', now()-'92d'::interval, '>90 days old, complete, standalone'),
(2, null, null, 'COMPLETE', now()-'92d'::interval, '>90 days old, complete, root of 3,4'),
(3, 2,    null, 'COMPLETE', now()-'92d'::interval, '>90 days old, complete, child of 2, parent of 4'),
(4, 2,    3,    'OPEN',     now()-'92d'::interval, '>90 days old, open, child of 2,3'),
(5, null, null, 'COMPLETE', now()-'92d'::interval, '>90 days old, complete, root of 6,7'),
(6, 5,    null, 'COMPLETE', now()-'92d'::interval, '>90 days old, complete, child of 5, parent of 4'),
(7, 5,    6,    'COMPLETE', now()-'10d'::interval, '<=90 days old, complete, child of 5,6' )
```

Delete all the records from the table which are

- older than 90 days
- in `COMPLETE` status.

If a row has a `root_id` or a `parent_id` and is `OPEN`,
then the `root_id` and the `parent_id` rows should not be deleted.

In the above table, the row with `id=1` should be deleted.

`id=2` and `id=3` are `COMPLETE` and older than 90 days but since `id=4` is `OPEN` and has `root_id=2` and `parent_id=3`, these three rows (`id in (2,3,4)`) should not be deleted.

`id=5`,`id=6` and `id=7` are all `COMPLETE` but `id=7` is not older than 90 days and has `root_id=5` and `parent_id=6`, so these three rows (`id=5`,`id=6` and `id=7`) should not be deleted.

I tried multiple ways with inner queries
but I am not able to write a query for this scenario.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xfbNIqyA)

Comment: Your second remark sounds redundant: You're already only deleting >90 days old rows with status `COMPLETE`, so neither `CLOSED` rows nor the <90 day young ones will ever be targeted. [@Laurenz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77451517/5298879) does exactly what you described: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UnBmjEH_). Still, I'm not sure if you want orphaned row 7 that's on its own too young to be removed, while its root and parent get wiped: the new remark you added sounds like you wanted to address that (5,6,7) case instead of repeating the (2,3,4).

Comment: @Zegarek - In the demo fiddle, the query which you have returns id 5. But id 5 is the root of id=7 which is COMPLETE but not older than 90 days.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, that's exactly what I was suspecting. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77452714/5298879) with a few more test cases in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

1. You want to remove only rows that are `COMPLETE` ***AND*** >90 days old.
2. If a row meets the 1. deletion criteria but is a child, parent or root of a row that cannot yet be deleted because it's still `OPEN` or too young, you don't want to remove any of the linked rows. Symmetrically: locked parent locks child, locked child locks parent.

```sql
DELETE FROM the_table t1
WHERE 'COMPLETE'=status AND now()-ts > '90d'::interval
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM the_table AS t2
                WHERE (   t1.id IN(t2.root_id,t2.parent_id)
                       OR t2.id IN(t1.root_id,t1.parent_id) )
                  AND (   'OPEN'=t2.status
                       OR now()-t2.ts <= '90d'::interval    )  )
RETURNING *;
```

| id | root_id | parent_id | status | ts | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | *null* | COMPLETE | 2023-08-09 11:14:25.445328 | >90 days old, complete, standalone |

I've added more test cases in [this db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FQUKqrua). At the end there's a case to be clarified: a removable parent with two children, one non-removable, one removable. If you allow the removable child to be deleted, while parent stays with the non-removable child, then this works. If you wish to keep the entire graph/family until all nodes/members are removable, you'll need a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) or a [routine](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) to traverse the graph.

Comment: we are facing the issue which you have mentioned in the end case. We want to keep the entire graph until all the nodes are removable. Can you pls help with some example for the recursive CTE for this use case.

Comment: @Nagesh I'd be happy to assist but you'd get more eyes on the problem if you concluded this thread and opened a new one; recursion it requires significantly complicates the solution or can even change it entirely. Be sure to **1)** add that last test case from my fiddle to the new question, **2)** [try to give it a shot](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) yourself and attach what you tried **3)** underline that the new thread's a reboot of this one (adding a link), but with recursion/full graph in mind **4)** post a link to the new thread here

Comment: Thank you again. I did that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77473273/delete-rows-based-on-age-status-and-existence-of-related-rows-with-recursion-in

Answer (score 0):

Translating your requirement into SQL, I get

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE status = 'COMPLETE'
  AND timestamp < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '90 days'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab AS t2
                  WHERE t2.status = 'OPEN'
                    AND (tab.id = t2.root_id OR tab.id = t2.parent_id)
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Step by step - first identify record `id`-s that are parents or roots of records with 'OPEN' status and store them in `t` CTE, then delete those records that are 'COMPLETE', older than 90 days and whose `id` is not in `t`. `ts = 'older than 90 days'` is illustrative.

```sql
with t (id) as 
(
 select unnest(array[root_id, parent_id])
 from the_table 
 where status = 'OPEN' 
   and (root_id is not null or parent_id is not null)
)
delete from the_table
where status = 'COMPLETE'
  and ts = 'older than 90 days'
  and id not in (select id from t);
```

DB-fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fmh2iQs3LKYbdGxVjS3zGq/1)

Comment: THanks for the query. We have another scenario. If any of the order ID is CLOSED and is not less than 90 days, then also the root and the parent of those orders should not be deleted. Updated the Fiddle.